# how to maintain more lookup data in a wcf application

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontext

I am writing a WCF service, uses Entity framework. My service has to refer look-up table data for each client call (nearly 10 look-up tables in sql server). So, I am planning to write a host application, will initialize static dbcontext, alternatively can I use MemoryCache to load lookup tables. Could you please give me a hint to follow best approach in this scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your caching needs are pretty small. Consider using Dictionary objects for the cache. You can use them to bind as well as to lookup descriptions quickly because they are keyed.